# Will i be denied from Jannah due to my son's sin

Tags: nikah, jannah, hajj

Assalamualaikkum,

My son has done "Civil Marriage" with a idol worshiping girl against without our consultation. Now me and husband are very worried that Allah will punish. We have below question

1. Will Allah punish me for his sins.
2. Are we allowed to perform hajj. Will Allah accept it.
3. Will Allah accept us to Jannah

Answer (score 1):

و عليكم السلام والرحمة الله وبركاته

You will not denied from Jannah due to your son's sin according to the below evidence. And yes you will be able to perform Hajj and inshaAllah Allah will accept your Hajj and he may admit into Jannah.

> And no bearer of burdens shall bear another's burden, and if one
> heavily laden calls another to (bear) his load, nothing of it will be
> lifted even though he be near of kin. Quran 35:18